# :thread-subject isn't picked up

Tags: mu4e

I've just started with `mu4e` and was mainly following the manual. For that reason I wanted to change the `:subject` in the headers view to `:thread-subject`. I've linked gmail with offlineimap and as far as I understood the option `:thread-subject` shouldn't repeat subjects for conversations. However, somehow it isn't picked up in my case. I've changed the mue4-headers.el like:

```
(defcustom mu4e-headers-fields
  '( (:human-date       .   12)
     (:flags            .    6)
     (:mailing-list     .   10)
     (:from             .   22)
     (:thread-subject   .   nil))
```

however, I still get displayed all subjects within a thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [longer configuration example](http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Longer-configuration.html#Longer-configuration) from the manual. I think it should be like this:

```
(setq mu4e-headers-fields
  '( (:human-date       .   12)
     (:flags            .    6)
     (:mailing-list     .   10)
     (:from             .   22)
     (:thread-subject   .   nil)))
```